# C++ lambda. How need to capture the pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, lambda, object-lifetime

For example, there is a method:

```
void foo( A* p )
{
    auto l = [=](){ /* Do Something using p */ };

   // Use l ...
}
```

How I should to capture the pointer: by reference or by value?
Inside lambda p is not changed, just used its methods.

Comment: By value should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that it is a pointer doesn't affect your decision about ref or value capture. Since a pointer is small enough and you don't want to write it, you can capture by value.

I usually use the following rule:

- if it's bigger than a pointer, use a reference because the copying might be more expensive than the dereference
- if you want to see changes from outside the lambda, obviously references are the only option
- otherwise (if it's small and doesn't change) capture by value

So a pointer that doesn't change should be captured by value. If the compiler detects that there are no writes, it might optimize a capture by reference and pass by value anyway, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer does not have methods (or, in C++ terminology, member functions). You probably mean you're only calling member functions of the object pointed to by `p`. Therefore, if you don't want to affect `p` itself, there is no need to capture it by reference. So just capture it by value, as you do now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a truly local lambda -- one whose lifetime does not exceed its scope -- capturimg by `[&]` is usually harmless.  In many situations, the references can be treated as pure aliases by reasonably smart compilers, and it makes ot behave like a 'local function' would.

If there is lots of state in your local scope, describing exactly what you capture is sometimes
 good.  And `=` on small cheap objects (like `int` or pointers) with trivial copy can also be treated much like an alias, especially with non `mutable` lambdas.

If however your closure outlives the local scope, `&` capture is unsafe, and I would even advise against `=` -- capture explicitly, and ensure any pointers captured have sufficient lifetime.

For pointers in particular, a modifying the pointer is completely different than modifying the data pointed to.  Capturing a copy of the pointer when you do not modify the pointer itself will not cause any problems.